# build a Model helper in laravel/lumen

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, lumen, lumen-5.3

i want to build custom model helper in lumen(laravel) and use it

```
User::listOption($listOption);
Product::listOption($listOption);
```

and $listOption is a json come from api like this

> {filters:[{property:"name",value:"john"}]

and result must include all user's whit name john

and i want to reuse this for any table

how to create this helper

Comment: Scopes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes